# Modality for radiology orders in ORM^O01 message

Tags: hl7, hl7-v2

Our DICOM Modality Worklist server is currently receiving HL7 `ORM^O01` orders from our hospital RIS. To map each order to a modality we are currently using the `OBR-24` field in the message. The codes contained in `OBR-24` are mapped to AE titles and modality by a lookup table in the MWL server. The current `OBR-24` values are something along the lines of "LOC_STATION", where LOC is the location (on building level) for the scheduled station and STATION is the scheduled station for the current order.

Now a need has arisen to direct the same incoming message feed to another system for prefetching prior studies from a slower long-time archive based on the orders. An important input parameter for the prefetch engine rules is the modality of the ordered study. Therefore we would like to add the DICOM modality code in the incoming order messages, since we do not want to duplicate the entire lookup tables system and manage it separately in two places.

What would the best field for this kind information be inside the `ORM^O01` structure as defined in v2.3.1 of HL7 standard? I have skimmed the standard and went through our MWL server vendor reference materials, but the closest I have found, is the same `OBR-24` field, which is already in use in our solution. Or should we look at implementing some kind of custom Z-segment?

The situation is additionally complicated by the fact, that we are an independent PACS service provider, therefore we do not control the development of the HIS/RIS softwares in the hospitals and mostly we have to integrate with existing systems with minimum modifications on their side. Therefore it is quite difficult to change or move any of the existing fields in our messaging standard, but it's easier to implement new unused fields for new purposes.

Comment: Could you give some examples of the code values that the RIS currently populates OBR-24 with?

Comment: I have added examples of the OBR-24 values to the first paragraph in the question.

Answer (score 3):

[IHE Radiology Technical Framework](http://www.ihe.net/Technical_Frameworks/#radiology) - Volume 2 (RAD TF-2): Transactions, `Appendix B: HL7 Order Mapping to DICOM MWL` also does not specify recommended mapping for DICOM tags

- `(0040,0001) Scheduled Station AE Title`
- `(0008,0060) Modality`.

In our ORM^O01 generator we use placer fields and filler fields (HL7 items #00251, #00252, #00253, #00254 - OBR-18..OBR-21) for the application entity title and the diagnostic service section id (HL7 item #00257 - OBR-24) for the modality code.

You can place your current routing information into the receiving facility field (MSH-6) and thus release the OBR-24 for another use.

MSH-6 (Receiving Facility, item #00006) was originally meant to represent part of the "receiver's address", the "LOC_STATION". While the MSH-5 indicates your PACS service address, the MSH-6 might be used to designate where next should the order go. This way you would not need to put the same information again into OBR-24 and you can use OBR-24 for just the modality code.

It should be ok to place it nearly anywhere as long as you document it in your **conformance statement** so that admins of the interface engines can define corresponding mapping.

If you can not change/influence the incoming message format then you may find useful some kind of universal field remapping service before the incoming message are processed or passed on to DICOM clients.

For an example of what I mean look at the XSLT mapping script used by the [dcm4che.org](http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/ee2/Home) open source DICOM Clinical Data Manager system with HL7/PACS/DICOM interfaces built-in. When a HL7 v2 message arrives, it is translated into its equivalent XML representation, transformed by a vendor-specific XSLT script and then pushed into a DICOM database storage. One of the default ORM^O01 mappings is in folder https://svn.code.sf.net/p/dcm4che/svn/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-arc/trunk/dcm4jboss-hl7/src/etc/conf/dcm4chee-hl7 in file `orm2dcm.xsl`

Comment: I did not think about looking up the IHE documents, thanks for a good hint. :) In regards to Your suggestions, they are quite reasonable, but difficult to implement in our case. I edited my original question and added a paragraph in the end explaining our situation regarding changes in our interface. Also, I do not fully understand Your reasons behing using MSH-6. But good answer nonetheless, gave me something to consider. :)

Comment: @TarmoR I have edited my answer regarding MSH-6 and linked a tip how one open source DICOM Modality Worklist server handles it. Is it better? Anything else I may help with?